# What is the name of a short story about a woman who was listening to the sound of the river?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I want to find the name of a short story and its writer.
The short story is about a woman that her husband has died in sleep.
When the police ask her about her whereabouts at the time of his death, she replies that she was listening to the sound of the river.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make this work easier to identify, please add any information you have of the kind listed at the [tag wiki for identification requests](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info). This includes details about where and when you read it, what the publication date seemed to be, what the book looked like, etc. Please [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/24827/edit) to add these details, don't provide them in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Sound of the River* by Jean Rhys appears to be a possibility.

From *The Cambridge Introduction to Jean Rhys* by Elaine Savory:

> It begins with third-person narrative: a couple is in bed, talking, and we enter in the middle of their conversation, just as the woman is expressing unfocused fear. It is a large fear, worse than the little fears she can recognize and name. On their walk earlier, she worried that the river was too silent, as if it were full. Now, lying in bed, she remembers her mother trying to teach her to deal with fear: “You're not my daughter if you're afraid of a horse” (CS:237). Her fear is persistent but vague. In the morning her husband is dead in bed. The doctor wants to know if she heard anything in the night, but she says she thought “it was a dream” (CS:240), and she admits she waited too long to go for help because of the sound of the river: it “got louder and closer and it was in the room with me.